# How to add via Information Link (to Oracle) a db field which is a static text

Tags: oracle, spotfire

I wish to add a static text like "Source name" As Sourcename, instead of some column values. Any ideas how to add this at the Info Link level ?
The db is Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that single quotes did the trick.

'TEXT' used in Expression field did work for me for Oracle db.